# Side menu, hide menu option programatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm using the side menu [jonkykong/SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu), the implementation is ok, but I have two roles in the application and some options are different to each one.

Well, I was thinking to write all the options in the menu and hide the no-necessary of them.

Someone has idea about how I can hide some options from my `ViewController` ???

Basically, the `Left Menu` has defined the class `SideMenuTableView` and each ellement is defined by a `UITableViewVibrantCell`

Comment: Would you be able to provide some of your controller code? It would be easier to help if we can see how you've implemented the menu.

Comment: Use protocol delegate pattern. I have done similar thing for MFSlider in my project. Otherwise you can access tableview of side menu controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have an complete idea of your code, but this might be rather simple.

If you are using a UITableView, why can't you just update the datasource and reload the menu table. Or even have two different arrays of them

Or the other way around it would be handling the items in height `tableView(:heightForRowAt:)` method. By setting the height 0 you can hide them.

With SideMenu you can also change your MenuViewController at runtime using `SideMenuManager.menuLeftNavigationController = newMenuController`, so that could be your last resort.